# HTML + java script Count Row help and Javacript is not recognizable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie in coding-some experience in python. Our company(Finance) is using software called Xceptor to process the data and adding the function of including the table in the message body with HTML. But one thing that really bothers me is when there's no information in the **Listfield**, I want to output text only and doesn't show the table. Display header and content when there is something, including a sentence indicating how many. Is it possible? Here is the sample script.It works well in W3 school editor but **script** part doesn't work in that platform I am using.Does any one have any suggestion for that?
Thank you for your help and have a good one.

```
<table border="1" id="MyTable">
<p id="count"></p> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Record Type</th> 
        <th>Trade Date</th> 
        <th>Account</th> 
        <th>Transaction</th> 
        <th>Traded Asset</th> 
        <th>Proceed CCY</th> 
        <th>Settlement Date</th>
        <th>Quantity Traded</th> 
        <th>SHORTNAME</th> 
        <th>ACCT_ID</th> 
    </tr> 
    {[List Field]}  
</table>
<script>
var rowCount = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
if(rowCount <= 1 ) {
document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = "none";
} else{
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "There are "+(rowCount-1) +"row(s)";}
</script>
```

Comment: As you are " using software to process the data and adding the function of including the table in the message body with HTML" you might as well use the same software and function to actually generate the output you want. ;-)

Comment: Hi Carsten,Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately,the software can not perform the function I want, but it's HTML recognizable, so I am to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Identity strings are case sensitive. You misspelled it in your version. With `document.getElementById("MyTable");` it will work:

```js
const tbl = document.getElementById("MyTable"), rows=tbl.rows.length-1
if(rows)
 document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = `There ${rows==1?"is one row":`are ${rows} rows`}`;
else tbl.style.display="none";
```

```html
<p id="count"></p>
<table border="1" id="MyTable"> 
<tr> 
    <th>Record Type</th> 
    <th>Trade Date</th> 
    <th>Account</th> 
    <th>Transaction</th> 
    <th>Traded Asset</th> 
    <th>Proceed CCY</th> 
    <th>Settlement Date</th>
    <th>Quantity Traded</th> 
    <th>SHORTNAME</th> 
    <th>ACCT_ID</th> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td>Type</td> 
    <td>Trade Date</td> 
    <td>Account</td> 
    <td>Transaction</td> 
    <td>Traded Asset</td> 
    <td>Proceed CCY</td> 
    <td>Settlement Date</td>
    <td>Quantity Traded</td> 
    <td>SHORTNAME</td> 
    <td>ACCT_ID</td> 
</tr> 
{[List Field]}  
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Carsten, thank you for your reply.After fixing the case sensetive issue, yours or mine script are still unrecognizable for Xceptor. I will get in touch with them and see why.Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

HTML is a markup language and not programming language so you cannot use if statements in HTML. You will need to do it with help of Javascript.

Comment: Thank you and do you have any recommendations on where I can get some info?

Comment: @Suuuuuu I don't know how I can help you with that but you need to have good grasp of js and html for that. For a beginning you can refer here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).